# Publishing event from Azure DevOps to Azure Event Grid

Tags: azure-devops, webhooks, azure-eventgrid

I am using a webhook to publish events to an Azure Event Grid Topic whenever an action is updated. But when I use the access key from the topic to authenticate the request, I see error like

[image: Error]

What am I doing wrong?

[Reference for Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/security-authenticate-publishing-clients)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
https://<yourtopic>.<region>.eventgrid.azure.net/api/events?aeg-sas-key=<your url encoded key>
```

and the following is an Event Schema of the payload:

```
[
  {
    "topic": string,
    "subject": string,
    "id": string,
    "eventType": string,
    "eventTime": string,
    "data":{
      object-unique-to-each-publisher
    },
    "dataVersion": string,
    "metadataVersion": string
  }
]
```

**UPDATE:**

The example of the HttpTrigger function with output binding to the AEG custom topic:

run.csx:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid.Models;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(JObject body, IAsyncCollector<EventGridEvent> outputEvents, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"{body.ToString(Formatting.Indented)}");

    EventGridEvent ege = new EventGridEvent() {
        Topic = null,
        Id = (string)body["id"],
        EventType = (string)body["eventType"],
        EventTime = (DateTime)body["createdDate"],
        Data = body,
        DataVersion = "1",
        Subject = "abcd"
    };
    await outputEvents.AddAsync(ege);

    return (ActionResult)new NoContentResult(); 
}
```

function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "body",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
         "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "eventGrid",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "outputEvents",
      "topicEndpointUri": "AEG_TOPIC_XX_ENDPOINT",
      "topicKeySetting": "AEG_TOPIC_XX_KEY"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}

enter code here
```

Comment: Had tried this earlier. That gives a separate error

Error Message
Unexpected token when reading JSON. Expected: StartArray, actual: StartObject.

Comment: did you try it using the postman or some rest client?

Comment: Note, that the event payload must be an array, see event schema https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema

Comment: Based on the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops, I do recommend to use an azure function (HttpTrigger) with an output binding for AEG, see details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-output?tabs=csharp

Comment: Aha! I was using the Test button on the Webhook to test this out and it wasn't working, I now looked at the request sent and it is not in the specified event schema. I tested using postman with the example in the link and I see 200. Looks like I won't be able to send events directly to event grid from ADO using webhooks. Only option I know is to intercept the request by logic apps and then forward in the specified format to event grid. Thanks a ton.

Comment: That's correct, the problem is ADO Event schema such as a single object and the AEG Event schema required an array of the events (included also for single event). I have noted to the AEG team about this issue many times, it should be the same way like we have for CloudEventSchemaV1_0, where the content-type is indicated a batch of the events.

Comment: I have added a working example for integration ADO webhook to the AEG custom topic endpoint.

Comment: Hi @RomanKiss, I created a webhook with url as u have mentioned, not sure where should I pass function.json?

Answer (score 0):

Accorrding to your error message:

> This is due to the reason: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.

The length of your url encoded key may not be a multiple of 4.

To solve this problem, add `=`s to the end of your key until the length of the key is a multiple of 4.

As the link your attached shows:

```
aeg-sas-key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX0GXXX/nDT4hgdEj9DpBeRr38arnnm5OFg==
```

The original key was `nDT4hgdEj9DpBeRr38arnnm5OFg`, but in order to make it a Base-64 string, two `=`s were added after it, making it `nDT4hgdEj9DpBeRr38arnnm5OFg==`.

Comment: it looks like the problem for using its webhook for posting an event to the custom topic endpoint is in the payload schema, see comments to my answer.